# access app config from different project in an application

Tags: c#, app-config

I have tested to retrieve  "configsection" data from app config using c# and it works fine. However, I am facing problem to access these configuration from a different project code. My application is build up of several projects as a bundle. if the app config is in the main project and i want to access that/want to write that from code of another project, how to do that please? I have tried and it throwings errors like as follows:

> An error occurred creating the
>   configuration section handler for
>   XXXXX: Could not load type
>   'XXXXX.XXXXXXX' from assembly
>   'System.Configuration,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   (F:\XXXX\XXXXX.XXXXX\bin\Release\XXXX.XXXXX.XXXX.exe.Config
>   line 4)

Comment: Please share with us the code you use to read/write the config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create a class in your main project from which you will get all the items from app config.

From other projects, call this method and get the desired property.

Comment: I agree, i have worked like this before.
What you do is make a new file entirely for access to your config file. At the startup of your program, make sure to call the init method there, so that you read all (necessary) data into that file. So what should be present there are some props and functions to read/write to your config.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you would be able to access it directly.

One way would be to pass the required values as parameters to the instances created from a different project.

I would also like to know if it would be possible to access it directly.